# Remove all whitespaces between non words?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, regexp-replace

How can I remove all spaces between non words from a column?
I have a column with values like that:

```
"This Is My - Value"
"This Is My- Value"
"This Is My/ Value"
"This Is My- Value (Other -Value)"
```

How can I remove all whitespaces between non words, like so:

```
"This Is My-Value"
"This Is My-Value"
"This Is My/Value"
"This Is My-Value(Other-Value)"
```

Tried this, but is not working:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(I,"\s*([^a-zA-Z\d\s:])\s*","\\1") FROM registros;
```

Comment: The following characters between quotes "()-/\"

Comment: Is this mysql or oracle? I don't believe mysql has REGEXP_REPLACE function.

Comment: MySql, it does :)

Comment: MySQL regular expressions don't have escape sequence like `\s` and `\d`.

Comment: See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html for the documentation of regexp syntax in MySQL.

Comment: @clinomaniac, MariaDB has implemented a REGEXP_REPLACE() function, more or less similar to the one in Oracle and PostgreSQL.  MySQL doesn't have that function.

Comment: Thank you @BillKarwin. I was wondering what I was missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(I,"\[[:blank:]]*([-/()])\[[:blank:]]*","\\1") FROM registros;
```